# magento CE 1.9 color swatches

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

I am using magento C.E. 1.9.1 swatch functionality.

I have enable color and size swatch from backend and I have configure one product.

When I go to detail page its show dropdown option instead of swatches.

can any one help me how to solve this.

Comment: have you uploaded swatches images.

Comment: yes I do uploaded swatches images

Comment: If you're not using the default RWD theme, then it will not work. You need to copy some files from the RWD theme to your current theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the javascript and functionality of the 1.9.1 color swatch features is built into the rwd/default package/theme, and not any other package/theme. Most templates are built on default/default or base/default which do not include that functionality.

otherwise, the detailed how-to is here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee1141-ce191-configurable-swatches

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to look at...
Are you using the rwd theme (or a customized version of it)?
Do you have images on all of your associated products?